# Convergence of the following sequence of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence

A friend recently came across the following problem in his research and I wasn't able to find a general proof of it. 
Let $A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
(1-b) & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & b \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ where $b \in (0,1)$ and consider the sequence $(A^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. 
It seems to me that this sequence is convergent, however I am unsure how to prove it.
My current progress has been: \

1. The characteristic polynomial is $\chi_A(X) = X^n + (b-1)X^{n-1} - b$
2. This polynomial has a zero in $X=1$

It is fairly easy to prove that all zeros of this polynomial lie in $\overline{B_1(0)} = \{x \in \mathbb{C}: |x| \leq 1\}$. Moreover I believe that the polynomial should have $n$ distinct zeros and all other zeros other that 1 should be in $B_1(0) = \{x \in \mathbb{C}: |x| < 1\}$.

It would be sufficient to show this as we would then get some $S \in Gl_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A = SDS^{-1}$ where $$D = \mathrm{diag}(1,x_2, \dots, x_n)$$ where $x_2, \dots, x_n$ are the remaining zeros.

This would of course then imply
$$A^n = SD^nS^{-1}$$
which tends to $S\cdot \mathrm{diag}(1,0,\dots,0) \cdot S^{-1}$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

I don't know if this is the right way to approach this problem or if there is a far more elegant solution. Another idea we had was that the vector space $\left<(1,b, \dots, b)\right>$ is the Eigenspace of $A$ associated with 1 (when multiplied from the left side). We tried to apply something like the Banach fixed-point theorem but weren't successful as the matrix wasn't a contraction in the spaces we looked at.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial you have found is not correct ! It should read $\chi_A(X) = X^n + (b-1)X^{n-1} .$

Comment: Hello :) @Fred There is a $b$ in the right upper corner. So at least for $n=3$ the characteristic polynomial is correct. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1-b+%2C+0+%2C+b+%7D%2C+%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%7D

Comment: Ooops ! I overlooked the $b$ in the right upper corner

Comment: Dividing out the zero $X=1$ we get the polynomial $X^{n-1} + b(X^{n-2} + \dots + X + 1)$. Going from $b=0$ to $b=1$ we go from the roots of the polynomial $X^{n-1}$ (of which there is of course only one: 0) to the roots of the polynomial $X^{n-1} + \dots + 1$ which are just the $n$-th roots of unity except one. It seems to me that the zeros would trace out some "path" to the roots of unity which would give a reason for the distinctness of the roots of $\chi_A$.

Comment: Write it out explicitly in the $3\times 3$ case; calculate $A^2$ and $A^3$, Note the pattern; show the pattern holds for all $n$ by induction.

Comment: Helo :) Let $g(x):= (1-b)x^{n-1}$ and $\displaystyle f(x)=b\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k$. If you can show $|f(x)|>|g(x)|$ for all $x\in \partial B_1(0)$, then by Rouche's theorem $f(x)+g(x)=\frac{\chi(x)}{x-1}$ and $f$ have the same number of roots in $B_1(0)$, but $f$ has no roots in $B_1(0)$. Hopefully it holds $|f|>|g|$ on the boundary.

Comment: This converges -- standard Perron-Frobenius or Markov Chain arguments give the result.

Comment: Oh damn thats cool, yeah, I didn't even think about Markov Chains! Thank you!